# Ember-cli calling php methods

Tags: php, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an ember.js application running in Apache that calls php methods, hits mySql and data is returned.

I created a new ember-cli application and copied my js, handlebars and php code into the cli structure. I run "ember build" then "ember server" and I can access my home page via localhost:4200.

When I hit the link that's supposed to get my data, I'm now getting a "304 Not Modified" returned from my php call along with the contents of my php file.

When I setup Apache I had to install php. Is there something special I have to do to run php in the ember-cli structure?

Comment: Try using a REST client to hit your PHP service.  If you see the contents of the PHP file (as opposed to the JSON results), then you probably don't have Apache configured correctly.  Not an Ember issue.

Comment: I believe that I'm using the REST adapter: export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({... I can look at Apache again, but it was working before I switched to ember-cli

Comment: When I run "ember server" does that use my installed Apache or is there something embedded in ember-cli that's serving up the pages?

Comment: `ember server` uses broccoli (a node package) to serve up your app. So, it's not using Apache.